# How should I call "session()->forget('data')"?

Tags: database, laravel, session

I have a function to store data in condition that the user has no current session.

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    $ip = Request::ip();
    $time = now();

     if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('name'))  { 
         UserInfo::storeUser();
          session()->put('name',$user->name);
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,
            ];
        }
    });
```

I've been said that when the user logged out I should delete session data like this

```
session()->forget('name');
```

So I created this function in LoginController

```
public function logout() {
   session()->forget('name');
 }
```

And I call it like this

```
 Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

As I result

I see blank page when trying to logout.

So I am afraid I don't understand how to properly write this function or where to call it do delete data from session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want that users should logout, you need to call the logout method on the authenticated user and then redirect them to whichever page you want them to. Generally, it is the welcome page of the application.

You need to replace the contents of `logout()` method with the following :

```
/**
 * Logout the user and redirect them to the welcome page.
 *
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectRespose
 */
public function logout()
{
    auth()->logout();

    session()->forget('name');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: @Brad_Fresh Anytime. Glad I could help.